# Unnesting a variable in SQL with multiple levels of nesting

Tags: sql, nested

I'm trying to run a query to select uplink capacity:

```
SELECT
  AirmaxStatus.Wireless.Sta.Airmax.UplinkCapacity   
FROM
  `commonwealth-networks.ds.radio_status` 
WHERE MacAddress = 'f2:7f:c4:e2:61:a8'
And date(created) >= '2018-03-06'
ORDER BY created desc
```

and I'm getting the error

```
Cannot access field Airmax on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<Airmax 
STRUCT<DownlinkCapacity INT64, UplinkCapacity INT64, Rx STRUCT<Cinr 
INT64>, ...>, Chainrssi ARRAY<INT64>, Distance INT64, ...>>
```

I've tried to unnest the query, but I haven't been able to do so successfully:

```
SELECT
   wireless 
FROM
  `commonwealth-networks.ds.radio_status`,
   UNNEST(AirmaxStatus.Wireless.Sta.Airmax.UplinkCapacity) wireless
WHERE MacAddress = 'f2:7f:c4:e2:61:a8'
And date(created) >= '2018-03-06'
ORDER BY created desc
```

AirmaxStatus.Wireless.Sta.Airmax.UplinkCapacity appears to have many arrays in one. How do I pull the UplinkCapacity?

Comment: What's your DB version?

Comment: When you say nested - do you mean XML, JSON? What is the format the nested data is stored in? Can you provide a sample of the nested data?